# Question tags in sentences with "let"

Tags: tag-questions

> Let them stay here

What is the correct question tag for this

> 1) will they?
>   2) will you?

My grammar book is suggesting first question tag, but I think second is correct. Please, help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

*Let them stay here* is a sentence in the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood), which is used when a command or request is being given.

The subject of imperative sentences—the person to whom this command or request is being given—is normally *you* (either singular or plural), although it's often left unstated.

In the sentence in the question, the command is being given to *you*, so that is what the tag needs to be:

> ✔ "(Hey, **you**!) Let them stay here, will **you**?"

Compare that to the alternative in the question:

> ✘ "(Hey, **they**!) Let them stay here, will **they**?"